# GDataXMLElement to raw xml string in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, cocoa-touch, gdata

I would like to get the string representation of a GDataXMLElement, including the tag, attributes, and children. For example,

`NSLog(@"%@", [e description]);`

Will give below output

```
GDataXMLElement 0x5f26720: {type:1 name:to xml:"<to>Tove</to>"}
```

But I want to get

```
<to>Tove</to>
```

I know I can format the string with some code, but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

once you have the element you can extract the string from it using...

```
NSLog(@"the values inside are %@",elementName.stringValue);
```

you can refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml) excellent tutorial by ray wenderlich..

EDIT:
if you want the complete XML as you stated in your comment you can use..

```
NSLog(@"the values inside are %@",elementName.XMLString);
```

Comment: This returns the text inside. What I wanted is raw XML.

Comment: Is there possibility, @Ankit Srivastava, to convert `GDataXMLElement ` to `NSArray` (when xml element contains array as single item)?